# game.physics.arcade.collide() in phaser js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I use framework phaser js.
I create a two circles using `graphics`

```
var graphics;
var ball;

var graphics1;
var ballHome;

function create(){
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);  

    graphics=game.add.graphics(500,500);    //first circle
    game.physics.arcade.enable(graphics);
    graphics.enableBody=true;
    graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,1);
    ball=graphics.drawCircle(10,10,15);
    graphics.endFill();


    graphics1=game.add.graphics(500,500);   //second circle
    game.physics.arcade.enable(graphics1);
    graphics1.enableBody = true;
    graphics1.beginFill(0xFFF55F,1);
    ballHome=graphics1.drawCircle(300,300,500);
    graphics1.endFill();

}

function update() {
     game.physics.arcade.collide(ball,ballHome); 
}
```

I want them to collide

Why does not `game.physics.arcade.collide(ball,ballHome)` work?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `collide()` function takes `Phaser.Sprite`s as its input, but `ball` and `ballHome` are not sprites; they are `PIXI.Graphics` objects. You need to create sprites from your `Graphics` objects, and then pass those sprites into `collide()`.

To make a sprite from your `graphics` object, first call `Graphics.generateTexture()` ([doc](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Graphics.html)) to create a texture, then call `game.add.sprite()` ([doc](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.GameObjectFactory.html)) with the texture you just created.

For more information on Phaser, plus loads of really helpful tutorials, see the [Phaser website](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/index).